# Can't upload binary with App Clip target to App Store - ERROR ITMS-90834

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-appclips

I added AppClip target to my project, and followed Apple's own documentation. It runs without any error on both simulator and real device.

As it's explained in related WWDC videos, and [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/configuring_your_app_clip_s_launch_experience), in order to configure default or advanced app clips experiences, apps have to be uploaded to App Store Connect.

I am using Xcode's Organizer to upload my binary, but I am receiving the following error.

```
ERROR ITMS-90834: 
"Unsupported content. 
This app contains an app clip. 
Apps with app clips cannot be submitted at this time."
```

[image]

How can I pass this? Is there any other way to configure and test App Clip launch experiences?

Comment: You have to be patient. We are probably still a couple of months away from iOS 14 release

Comment: That's true but I expected it to work because it's featured on WWDC sessions. Guess I was wrong :/

Comment: It is possible now to upload App Clips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App Clips should be fully operational now on iTunes

---

*Outdated answer:*

I found this answer by an Apple Engineer on [developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/650408).

> This feature will be available later this year but I can't provide an
> exact date. In the past, new features of TestFlight or App Store
> Connect were often made available before the general availability of
> iOS versions.

It looks like we need to wait some time to test App Clips.

Answer (score -1):

It's available now.It happened with the recent update of TestFlight (when they changed the TestFlight icon)